# android библиотеки быстрое создание объектов

Tags: java, android

Посоветуйте новичку библиотеки или какие-то сборки библиотек, помогающие в связи между объектами бд, программными классами, классами отображения (активностями) и макетами отображения для простых объектов. Например мне надо работать с объектом. Для этого мне надо создать таблицу со свойствами объекта, программный класс с этими же свойствами, класс активности который связывает программный класс и макет. При том что это обычный объект с каким-то простыми свойствами, которые просто надо хранить, отобразить и изменить пользователю. Подскажите какие-то библиотеки помогающие уменьшить количество кода.

В идеале я это вижу так. Создаю программный объект, описываю его свойства, подключаю какие-то события, связываю его с макетом и он автоматом создаст мне таблицу, в которой будет хранит свойства, свяжет свойства с элементами макетами, изменить программный объект, если пользователь изменил что-то на форме, изменить таблицу если пользователь нажал сохранить, прочитает все свойства из бд в элементы макета при создании активности

Т.е. что-то типа ORM только еще со связью активности и программного объекта.

Интересуют библиотеки для Java android с полностью открытым исходным кодом

Comment: Гугловский [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) насколько я понял, то что вам нужно